# Why ubuntu hangs so many times?

Tags: gui, vmware

I have recently started using linux - ubuntu 18.04 at work, so here is the list of apps I have installed that I need everyday:

- Skype
- JetBrains Rider C# IDE (runs on JVM only)
- IntelliJ IDEA Scala (runs on JVM only)
- JVM Oracle
- Postman
- Chrome

Here is the VM configuration (my company uses VMWare)

- 4GB RAM
- 1 processor/ 2 core.
- 50 GB SATA
- Network (Bridged mode)
- Sound/ Display (3D enabled with Auto Stretch)

now the problem is it keeps freezing for no obvious reason.

- when the build starts in Rider, it hangs.
- Sometimes opening more than 4 tabs in chrome hangs it.
- loading a workspace in postman hangs it.
- Rider IDE often gives error of out of memory during compilation sometimes

Sometime it takes 5-10 minutes to recover. sometimes I have to reset my machine (a virtual one off course). Surprisingly, a Windows 10 VM with identical hardware/software configuration runs smooth with no such problems.

so I'm pretty confused. All that is on internet that Hardware community is not so nice etc with LINUX hence it suffers native drivers. but to me it should not have any problem on a virtual machine.

so is this a common problem with LINUX that I'm facing everyday or is this me doing something wrong? and How do I fix it?

Comment: It seems like a RAM issue. Probably you're running out of RAM and it is using SWAP.

Comment: How much is recommended then?

Comment: How much swap space do you have? If you don't have enough swap space the system will constantly page the disk for available space that doesn't exist. Also what is swappiness set to? Sometimes swappiness is set too low which can actually make the system run slower as well if you regularly use too much ram (because ram maxes out before swap can take care of the problem). Other times, swappiness is set too high and you end up with too many read writes which can also slow the system down. Please include swapspace size and swappiness in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Recommended swap space for 4GB of ram is at least 4GB of disk space. This space is also used for suspending and hibernating.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the output of the following commands: `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness` and `free -h` It sounds like you may not have *enough* swapspace or you may have to adjust your swappiness setting higher or lower depending on what it is set at now. Swappiness is supposed to prevent  out of memory errors.

Comment: How much RAM is required depends on what you do with your system. Certain processes can be quite RAM intensive. I managed to fill 4Gb of RAM on my previous laptop, by having too many open apps and one of them starting a memory intensive task.

Comment: so I did a little experimentation and  increased and found out that minimum 6 GB RAM is required for the above apps. any configuration below 6 GB would start having problems. Although even at 8GB, the UI is not as fluid as it is even with a 4GB windows box. so maybe LINUX is more suited for background services and not for UI stuff. <= my conclusion